# How to checkout files from the command line and show UCM new activity GUI if neccessary

Tags: batch-file, clearcase, cleartool

I want to checkout some files from a batch script, but since we use UCM checking out files needs to be associated with an activity.  Is there an easy way to show the GUI for creating/selecting an activity to associate the checkout with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pop up the dialogue by using the cleardlg program with arguments /checkout .

Comment: Same with `/checkin`. I had to add the file path as the last parameter in order for the dialog to show up (which isn't really documented in the `/?` help popup).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ask for an activity name in your script, and then use the [`cleartool setactivity` command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setactivity.htm)

```
cleartool sectact -view viewTag -none       # make sure to unset any previous activity
cleartool sectact -view viewTag newActivity # set the new activity (name@\pvob)
```

You can launch the ClearCase Project Explorer (UCM GUI) with `clearprojexp`, but I don't think a "UCM activity dialog box" is available as a separate executable.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, however I need something that's useable by people who fear the command line and that can create new activities.  Seems cleardlg is the answer. :)